# Df calculations seem off in lmer with 3-level categorical predictor comparison

Tags: categorical-data, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom, lsmeans

This is a MLM analysis of a physiological variable (so big dataset) with a time x condition fixed effect, where condition has 3 levels. Model code is:

```
m.EDA1 = lmer(
  EDA_cs ~ Time_sd * Condition +
    (1 + Time_sd | Subject) +
    (1 + Time_sd | Video),
  data = data,
  control = lmerControl(
    optimizer = "bobyqa",
    calc.derivs = FALSE,
    optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e5)
  ),
  na.action = "na.exclude"
)
```

Note that I have separate random intercepts for subject and stimuli, as recommended by Judd et al (2012). Issue is that my design is weird in the sense that 2 of my 3 conditions  have the exact same same videos, while the third one has its own set of videos, because it was not possible to add that condition to the other videos. So video carries way more variability for that condition than for the other two, where the noise from the content of the video of the same for both.
I used statistical consulting at my university and they said it should be fine. However, I've noticed that when I do posthoc testing, the DF calculations are MASSIVELY different across my three conditions. For comparisons where the third "off" condition is included, df is 4, but for the other two with same video set, it's +30,000.
See:

```
emmeans(m.EDA,
        pairwise ~ Condition,
        mode = "satterth",
        lmerTest.limit = 33000)
```

Gives:

```
$contrasts
 contrast          estimate    SE       df t.ratio p.value
 A - B              0.0834  0.278     4.01   0.300  0.9522
 A - C             -0.1497  0.278     4.01  -0.538  0.8577
 B - C             -0.2331  0.015 31931.32 -15.584  <.0001
```

I am worried that this weird difference in df is symptom of some underlying issue with the analysis, possibly stemming from the stimuli design, but I'm not familiar with how dfs are calculated (beyond knowing that it's complicated and that some advocate for ignoring p-value calculations all together).

In a nutshell, my question is:
**Anyone knows if it's "ok" to have widely different dfs when posthoc comparing the different levels of a categorical variable in MLM?**

Comment: Let me guess -- B and C have the same video, and A has the different one. So B-C is a within-video comparison and the other comparisons are between-video. I think the df make sense from that perspective. The df for the means themselves are all three small - right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! A is the one with the different set. And yes, the dfs for the individual means are all around the same number.
What you say makes sense. But then the question is - is it ok for me to mix within and between video comparisons in the same analysis and same variable? or should I run 3 individual separate models (A-B, B-C, A-C)?

Comment: I have a related df question, not sure if to start another post. I've been following your (very useful) answers in other threads regarding emmeans and I was wondering if you could give me a hand. It’s regarding df calculation: if I do t-test satterthwaite in the emmeans the p-values contradict what the summary() function tells me, and they contradict common sense. A has the overall lowest mean, but appears as not different from B and C in post hoc (but B&C, who have closer means, are significantly different!). This goes back to within/between, where within has more power?